# Help me with this puzzle

Tags: puzzles

Look at this puzzle:

```
[FEN "r3q3/1pb1rbk1/2pn1p1p/p1Qp1Bp1/3P4/4P1NP/PP3PPB/3RR1K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

The aim of the puzzle is: Black to play and attain a good position. But I can't find a good position here. Then I looked at the solution, which was 1... Nc4!! . But I can't understand what happens after this move. I think both sides are equal. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Then the queen is trapped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Black will trap the queen on the next move, either with Bd6 or b6. For example:

```
[FEN "r3q3/1pb1rbk1/2pn1p1p/p1Qp1Bp1/3P4/4P1NP/PP3PPB/3RR1K1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Nc4 2. b3 Bd6 3. bxc4 Bxc5 4. dxc5 dxc4
```

and with a queen and a (passed) pawn for two minor pieces, Black will have no problems to win this game.

Comment: `b6` is still winning though it is not as good as Bd6.

Comment: I meant that ...b6 is necessary in a variation like 2. Nf1 Bxh2+ 3. Nxh2 b6.

Answer (score 2):

Wait it is not over yet :)

The queen trap from ..Nc4 can be avoided. White can give a check `1. ..Nc4 2. Nh4 ..Bxh4 3. Bxc7.`

You can also prevent the knight trapping the queen by giving that check beforehand. Thats another way around.

Apologies i am just a beginner, not good with chess notations, but he point is queen can be saved using Whites black bishop. I may be wrong.

Comment: I think you're right, though I am not sure it is any better.  Note, move 3 is `Bxc7` not `Bxc2`

Comment: Stockfish weeps at the score `2. Nc4` causes. The problem is that after your variation, the White Q is still trapped and falls to `b6`.